# Rspec test fails on Jenkins when open file from /tmp folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rspec, jenkins, tmp

I have such trouble with Jenkins.

I'm trying to test PDF generation using RSpec.

RSpec test failing, when trying to open receuntly generated PDF file. **(File is saving into /tmp directory)**

```
      //TEST
      pdf_generator = PdfGenerator::InvoicePdf.new(invoice)
      pdf_file_path = pdf_generator.to_pdf
```

and I get error(**in Jenkins only)**:

```
    Failures:

 1) OrdersController GET show while authorized as customer INVOICE .generate_pdf pdf contains correct text
 Failure/Error: pdf_file_path = pdf_generator.to_pdf
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory - /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TicketCo for Gerrit/workspace/tmp/1371464314.pdf
 # ./lib/pdf_generator/invoice_pdf.rb:80:in `to_pdf'
 # ./spec/controllers/orders_controller_spec.rb:413:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and here is the line in method, which causes error:

```
  def to_pdf
   Prawn::Document.generate(temp_pdf_file_path)
  ....
  end
```

Can someone help me with this trouble ?
Maybe I need to change PDF path for Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. If you have such problem just create /tmp folder in Jenkins workspace. In configurate tab you can add this command

```
     mkdir -p tmp
```